# Mysql display all records

Tags: php, mysql

I need an SQL query that displays all the records if its duplicated also. For instance say

```
select * from table where true and p_id in(1,2,1,1)
```

displays only records from 1 and 2 but i need it to be repeated when given in while loop.

**Update with code:**

```
$cook = unserialize($_COOKIE["pro_cook"]);
foreach ($cook as $something) {
  $merc[] = $something;
}
foreach ($size as $new_size) {
  $size_array[] = $new_size;
}

$items = count($merc);
$mer = rtrim(implode(',', array_reverse($merc)), ',');
$fulclr = "and p_id in (".$mer.")";
$asd = "(p_id,".$mer.")";
$result = mysql_query("select * from product_details where true ".$fulclr." order by field".$asd."");
```

Comment: Please write some code you have tried to achieve this

Comment: I think we're going to need more information. Can you show the code you currently have?

Comment: I would say you can't do it without a UNION or JOIN with the same table - and doing that dynamically based on the ids you are passing to the in clause is virtually impossible. I'd suggest you try to solve it in code instead of in the query.

Comment: You should add the code to your question @user3122677

Comment: Well it depens on your table structure if p_id coloumn is uniqe it's normal that you get just 2 rows but if its not uniqe you should get all rows which have the value of 1 and 2 select * from table where p_id in(1,2) is enough but as i said check the structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will help

```
$ids = "1,2,1,1";

$sql = "select * from table where true and p_id in (".$ids.")";
$rec = mysql_query($sql);

$dbData = array();
while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($rec)) {
    $dbData[$res['p_id']] = $res;
}

$ids = explode(',', $ids);

$newArray = array();
foreach ($ids as $id) {
   if (!empty($dbData[$id])) {
       $newArray[] = $dbData[$id];
   }
}
```

Comment: i think there is no difference between p_id IN (1,2) and p_id IN (1,2,1,1) by mysql so i dont get it your point. if there is multiple rows in db which has value of 1 or 2 he will get all of them with p_id IN (1,2) this is enough

Comment: the `p_id` supposed to be containing same values or different?

Comment: lets say our table has 5 rows and if two of them's p_id=1 and one of them's p_id=2 in this case  "p_id IN (1,2)" version will return 3 rows.

Comment: and if have only 2 records are there in the db then? i think the problem is clearly stating the problem.

Comment: i still dont get your point if there are 2 records in DB and if their p_id is 1 OR 2 you will get that 2 rows, if one of them's p_id=3 then u get only one row, etc.
p_id IN (1,2) statment sames as with this (p_id=1 OR p_id=2)

Comment: `displays only records from 1 and 2 but i need it to be repeated when given in while loop.` - mentioned in the question. and if you are confused about `$ids = "1,2,1,1";` then i have nothing to say.

Comment: well your fetching code is also overwrites the row which has the same p_id after your while loop you will see only 2 rows.

Comment: did you debug the code properly?? there is another `array` which will hold all the data according to the `$ids`

Comment: for example here is the table:
`1,foo`
`2,bar`
`3,abc`
`2,def`
with your sql we will get 3 rows right? which are `foo,bar,def` after your fetching code `$dbData` will shrink to `foo,def` and finally your `$newArray` will be like `(foo,def,foo,foo)` so you lost the row which is `bar` thats why i mention it

Comment: asked the same in 2nd comment.pretending it to be unique.i have answered depending on the question situation. thanks for your concern. and if the condition is what you are saying then this question will not be asked.

Comment: yes i get your point now.then we are in the same situation, i asked the the structure of table 1 hour ago at the comments of the question.